# Derivative to function ratio

Tags: derivatives

Is there a physical meaning for derivative of the function to function ratio? That is, this quantity,
$$
Q(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}
$$
Like for instance, if $f$ is the potential energy, this would be work to potential energy ratio. 
Or even what can we say about $Q(x)$, say when $Q(x)<0$.

Comment: This is the scaling factor of the derivitive to the function. This quantity gives an intuition of how the function relates to its gradient.

Comment: I also learned that this is called 'logarithmic derivative'. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^x \!Q(\xi) \, d\xi = \ln \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)} \iff \\
f(x) = f(x_0) \exp {\int\limits_{x_0}^x \! Q(\xi) \, d\xi}
$$
An example would be a [radioactive decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay#One-decay_process) process ($Q$: decay constant)

Another: [light absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law#Derivation) ($Q$: attenuation coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

It is also $\frac {d(\ln(f(x))}{dx}$.    Note that it has units of the units of $f$ divided by length, so it can be a scale length that shows how quickly $f$ changes.

Answer (score 1):

I know in Physics they use that $\frac{dN}{dt}=Nk$
for various uses so you could use it to show whether a relationship is exponential or not

Comment: I get that - I know the relationship is exponential but wanted to know the physical significance of it. Like mvw says, attenuation coefficient gives a good meaning to it.

Comment: Hmmm I think it is quite hard to give a general meaning to something like that, you could also see it as some kind of relative stability.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)$ measures the size of the population, and $t$ is time, then $Q(t)=f'(t)/f(t)$ is the rate of change of the population *per capita*.

For example, if each individual reproduces at a constant rate $r$, then $f'(t)/f(t)=r$, so we get exponential population growth $f(t)=f(0) \, e^{rt}$.

But if the per capita growth rate decreases linearly with the size of the population (due to limited resources, for example), $f'(t)/f(t)=r(1-f(t)/K)$, we get [logistic growth](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can see that in case of basic exponential/logistic model. What if $f(t)$ is the rate $r(t)$, where the growth rate $r$ depends on time? How do we interpret it?

Comment: You mean $Q(t)$? Then you get something which I don't know a name for, but which can be solved by separation of variables: $f'/f=r$ gives $\int df/f=\int r(t) \, dt$, etc.

Comment: No, then I mean the quantity $r'(t)/r(t)$. I know $r$ follows exponential as well, but I don't know what the quantity would mean. It is some sort of relative rate of change of growth over time.

Comment: Well, if $r(t)$ is the per capita growth rate, then $r'(t)/r(t)$ is rate of change of the per capita growth rate per per capita growth rate... :-)